# Which of these two ways of storing multiple static managers are best for performance?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Are these two setups equal in terms of memory-usage and performance?

I'm currently using singeltons to access different managers in my system. But I've noticed that the singelton Get() functions take a fair chunk of the performence because they are called quite often. (I thought the compiler would optimize that, but apparently not)

So I started looking for ways to change this.

One way was just to put them in a big shared-state class.
But I'm still working and modifying these managers. So I want to forward declare them, to avoid recompiling (a full recompile takes about 15 minutes).

But then I though, doesn't 'new' put them in another memory position. Not the same as static declared non-pointer variables.

**Question 1: How does these two solutions compare to each other, in terms of performance?**

**Question 2: And are they faster than a simple singleton-pattern?**

```cpp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Way 1: Shared State
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// .h

class SharedState
{
    // Just put all managers here
    static ObjectManager1 manager1;
    static ObjectManager2 manager2;
    static ObjectManager3 manager3;
    static ObjectManager4 manager4;

    // Class things
}
```

or

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Way 2, Shared State (With pointers)
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// .h 

class SharedState
{
    // Just put all managers here
    static ObjectManager1* manager1;
    static ObjectManager2* manager2;
    static ObjectManager3* manager3;
    static ObjectManager4* manager4;
}

// .cpp
ObjectManager1* SharedState::manager1 = new ObjectManager1();
ObjectManager2* SharedState::manager2 = new ObjectManager2();
```

EDIT:
Way 3: This should make them not be created by heap-memory? And still allow for forward decl.?

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Way 3
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// .h 

class SharedState
{
    // Just put all managers here
    static ObjectManager1* manager1;
    static ObjectManager2* manager2;
    static ObjectManager3* manager3;
    static ObjectManager4* manager4;
}

// .cpp`
// Defines them static/global here 
static ObjectManager1 g_Manager1;
static ObjectManager2 g_Manager2;
static ObjectManager3 g_Manager3;

// Set the class ptrs
static SharedState::ObjectManager1* manager1 = &g_Manager1;
static SharedState::ObjectManager2* manager2 = &g_Manager2;
static SharedState::ObjectManager3* manager3 = &g_Manager3;
```

Comment: Heap allocation is in general slower than static allocation and that's about all one can say without a specific system in mind.

Comment: But it will cost me a lot in compiling time. Is there another solution that I'm missing? I guess I could just transfer to static allocation when I'm finished though.

Comment: Compiling time is not even an argument when discussion program design.

Comment: It is in this case because it's a large deal for me. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: I think the whole question is founded on a misconception: `static` class members can have incomplete type (except, of course, at their definition and any non-trivial use).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, it seems to run well, but I edited my post to fix any compile issues. And I added a third way, which should be both static allocation and still allow me forw. decl. Making them static allocated in the .cpp should be equal to the performence in way1? Is that correct?

Comment: This isn’t really an answer and looks hideous in a comment, but here goes: `struct M1; struct M2; struct S {static M1 m1; static M2 m2;};` is a valid header, followed by `struct M1 {}; struct M2 {};` in another header (or two) and `M1 S::m1; M2 S::m2;` in a (single) source file.  How that’s more *useful* than an ordinary `extern M1 m1;` I’m not sure, unless the access control is what you want.